# Loading MKMapView asynchronously?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

When I first bring up an MKMapView my app seems to pause while it loads. I am assuming this is because it doesn't load asynchronously.

Is there any way I can get around this. While it loads you can't switch tabs or do anything.

Thanks

EDIT: here is my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

    NSArray *mapTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Standard",@"Satellite",@"Hybrid",nil];

    mapType = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:mapTypes];
    [mapType setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [mapType setCenter:CGPointMake(210, 345)];
    [mapType setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [mapType setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [mapType addTarget:self action:@selector(changeType:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:mapType];

    // refresh button...
    UISegmentedControl *refreshButton = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Refresh",nil]] autorelease];
    [refreshButton setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [refreshButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width-((refreshButton.frame.size.width/2)+5),(refreshButton.frame.size.height/2)+5)];
    [refreshButton setMomentary:YES];
    [refreshButton setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateMarkers) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:refreshButton];


    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"List" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToList)] autorelease];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:leftBarButton animated:YES];

    // refresh label
    refreshView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-74, 40)];
    [refreshView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8]];
    [refreshView.layer setCornerRadius:5];
    [self.view addSubview:refreshView];

    UILabel *refreshLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, refreshView.frame.size.width-10, refreshView.frame.size.height-10)] autorelease];
    [refreshLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [refreshLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [refreshLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
    [refreshLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [refreshLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [refreshLabel setText:@"Move the map and press 'refresh' to load new results."];
    [refreshView addSubview:refreshLabel];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:refreshView selector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Can you provide some specific code.

Comment: Nor do I - the documentation says it loads asynchronously and there are delegate methods. Basically the map is grey with a grid and from that point until it completely loads and puts the user's current location on the map it just pauses for a bit. Obviously the weaker the internet connection the longer it pauses. I will provide the `viewDidLoad` method. The rest of the class is huge.

Comment: edited op - the next thing doesn't happen till `didUpdateUserLocation` and that just centers the map on the user location and zooms.

Comment: Sorry when you say "pauses" you mean the UI thread is blocked as in you can't navigate away to another view or otherwise interact with UI?

Comment: yeah... thats right, the map won't move, you can't change tabs, button's don't work. :)

Comment: I ran this no problems observed. Had to declare mapType and refreshView. I think you must have something else going on outside of what you shared here.

Comment: hmm, well I stripped it down to just the map view and its still pausing. I'll try it again - start from the beginning. Thanks for your help though.