# Loading MKMapview in background to avoid delay issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, mkmapview

I'm building an iPhone app (in iOS 5) with several different views, one of which contains a map (also has separate view controller). The first time I go over to this view, it takes a while for it to load, and things such as animating pin drops also don't work well as a result of it. Not to mention that it takes a bit for the location to stabilize.

What I want to know is if there's a way to load MKMapView before a user goes to that view, so by the time they get there, these issues aren't present anymore.

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969589/loading-mkmapview-asynchronously) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585073/load-mkmapview-in-background-and-create-uiimage-from-it-iphone-ipad) question but they haven't been very helpful. Keep in mind that I don't really need to interact with that view before I get there, I just want it to be fully loaded by the time I go there.

Comment: Have you tried loading the map view at an earlier stage -- and marking the view as hidden -- then later just unhiding the view when you're ready to display it?

Comment: just wondering if you ever got this figured out? I'm having a similar issue!